# Validate model field in single line

Tags: python, django

```
 approximation = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=None)
```

I need to validate this field. It should be greater than 0 but i don't want to make function.

Answer (score 1):

If the value has to be greater or equal to zero, you can use `PositiveIntegerField` instead of `IntegerField`.

If the value has to be strictly greater than zero, you can add a validator:

```py
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from django.db import models

approximation = models.IntegerField(
    null=False,
    default=None,
    validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Meta class as follows:

```
from django.db import models

class Example(models.Model):
    approximation = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=None)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(approximation__gt=0), name='approximation_gt_0'),
        ]
```

Sources:

[Constraint option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.constraints)

[Constraint reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/constraints/)

This will add a Check constraint into your database.